# How to change language in Stripe - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm setting up a webshop in Woocommerce and Stripes payment checkout is set to English.

I have tried to read Stripes documentation, and it says that you have to insert a line of code `data-locale="auto"` to change the language, but I can't figure out what file I have to add the line of code to.

Where do I add the `data-locale`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a child theme you can add this code to the child theme `functions.php` file to set the locale to auto.

```
function tbz_wc_change_stripe_checkout_locale( $locale ) {
    return 'auto';
}
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_checkout_locale', 'tbz_wc_change_stripe_checkout_locale' );
```